# There's no shipping tax on woocommerce order dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The shipping tax costs displays everywhere except in the order dashboard.
[image]
I'm adding shipping costs programmatically so I assume the error is probably there? But at the same time doesn't make sense because the shipping tax is applied at the checkout with no issues.
Any tips where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it was the code..
I was trying this code that is popular to apply taxes in filter woocommerce_package_rates:

```
$taxes = array();
// Taxes: Loop through the shipping taxes array (as they can be many)
foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
    if( $tax > 0 ){
        $initial_tax_cost = $tax; // Get the initial tax cost

        $tax_rate    = $initial_tax_cost / $initial_cost; // Get the tax rate conversion

        $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate; // Set the new tax cost in taxes costs array

    }
}
$rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
```

Well in my case the $tax was alywas 0. So I discarded the whole thing and had it applying like this:

```
 $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = [$new_cost * $tax_rate];
```

It worked in checkout but not on order dashboard thus I asked the question.

Changed to this:

```
$taxes = WC_Tax::calc_shipping_tax( $rate->cost, WC_Tax::get_shipping_tax_rates() );
$rate->set_taxes($taxes);
```

I don't know why the index must be greater than 0..but well..Everything works now.